# Fail a Jenkins build when a Taurus-run JMeter test records a failure

Tags: testing, jenkins, load, blazemeter, taurus

I've got some tests setup to run via Taurus and kicking them off in a Jenkins stage like so:

```
...previous stages...

stage('Load Tests'){
  dir('./tests'){
     bat "bat _testFile.yml"
  }
}

...stages to execute if Load Tests stage succeeds
```

I want to bail out of the whole build if any one of the iterations in any of my tests fails. But this setup, as well as wrapping in a try/catch don't work.

Answer (score 0):

My fault. The fail criteria were not properly implemented. Now that they are, the above 'successfully' fails the jenkins build when the criteria are not met.

Comment: Could you share your findings? I am having the same issue. My job always ends up as unstable, but never fails.